# Simplification of summation of combinations

Tags: probability, summation, combinations

Please refer below:-
The equations are excerpted from [IEEE magazine](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8069007)

$ \mathbb {P}_{\mathrm {ra}} = \mathbb {P}\left ({ x > 0 }\right ) = 1 - e^{-\lambda }\; \tag{1}$

$\mathbb {P}_{0} = {\left ({ 1-\mathbb {P}_{\mathrm {ra}} }\right )}^{ N-1}\; \tag{2}$

$\mathbb {P}_{n}= \binom {N-1}{n} \mathbb {P}_{\mathrm {ra}}^{n} {\left ({ 1-\mathbb {P}_{\mathrm {ra}} }\right )}^{ N - n-1}\; \tag{3}$

$\mathbb {P}_{\mathrm {acc}} \left ({n,0}\right ) = \left ({\frac {K-1}{K}}\right )^{n}\; \tag{4}$

$\mathbb {P}_{\sum } = \sum _{n=1}^{N-1}\mathbb {P}_{n}\mathbb {P}_{\mathrm {acc}} \left ({n,0}\right )\; \tag{5}$

From (2) and (5)

$\mathbb {P}_{s}=\mathbb {P}_{0} + \mathbb {P}_{\sum }={\left ({\frac {e^{-\lambda }+K - 1}{K}}\right )}^{N-1}\; \tag{6}$

Here $\mathbb {P}$ refers to probability

I am unable to understand how adding eqn. (2) and (5) result in the expression in step (6)

Edit:
Thanks to @RobPratt

The expansion from equations would yield a binomial expression of the form:-
$ (e^{-\lambda})^{N-n-1} ((1-e^{-\lambda})(\frac{K-1}{K}))^{n}\;\;$

$ (e^{-\lambda} + (1-e^{-\lambda})(\frac{K-1}{K}))^{N-1}$

Further simplification would result in expression as derived in equation (6)

Comment: Thanks @RobPratt.. sometimes things are in front of the eyes.. but one cannot see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the binomial theorem to
$$\left(\frac{e^{-\lambda}+K-1}{K}\right)^{N-1} 
= \left(\frac{K-1}{K} + \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{K}\right)^{N-1},$$
yielding
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}{n} \left(\frac{K-1}{K}\right)^n \left(\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{K}\right)^{N-1-n},$$
and split $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}$ into  $\sum_{n=0}^0+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}$.

Comment: Do you imply $\sum_{n=0}^1$ ?

Comment: No, $\sum_{n=0}^0$ means a one-term sum with $n=0$.  The $n=1$ term is part of the other sum $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}$.